# Unable to step over in WebStorm running Node.js application

Tags: node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm able to hit a breakpoint, inspect variables, etc., but when I click the "step over" button, it doesn't debug to the next line.  I just see "Frames are not available."  Right now I have the breakpoint at app.init().  Step into doesn't work, only force step into works.  I'm running Windows 8.1 and WebStorm 11.0.1.

```
function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
  app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
  app.init();
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem.

Try this:

1: Open settings in webstorm -> find "build, Execution, Deployment" section -> find "debugger" -> open "Stepping".

2: uncheck "Do not step into library scripts"

Then try again, it will be normal now.